# Android Location sometimes is too old

Tags: android, android-location

I am having a weird problem when I am trying to get the device location in android.

Sometimes it gets the current location well, but some other times it keeps returning an old location. And by old I mean like several days old and tens or even hundreds of kilometers from where it should be located.

I dont know what I am doing wrong, I have tryied several different ways to get the location, but it seems that every method has the same problem.

The most weird thing is that it does not happen in every device... or at least that is what it seems. Samsung S3 and S4 are the most affected, but in my nexus 4 it has never happened.

This is my code, maybe you see something wrong:

```
    public void startSearchingLocation() {

        // Define a listener that responds to location updates
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                // Called when a new location is found by the network location
                // provider.


                makeUseOfNewLocation(location);

            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                    Bundle extras) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            }

        };

        String provider = getProvider();

        /*I ignore the passive provider*/
        if (provider == null
                || provider.contains(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER)) {
            this.validProvider = false;
        } else {
            this.validProvider = true;
        }
        if (validProvider) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, time, distance,
                    locationListener);

        }
    }

    protected void makeUseOfNewLocation(Location location) {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

        try {
            obj.put("latitude", location.getLatitude());
            obj.put("longitude", location.getLongitude());
            obj.put("provider", location.getProvider());
            locationResult = obj;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public JSONObject getLastKnownLocation() {
        if (locationResult != null) {
            return locationResult;
        } else {
            String provider = getProvider();
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            if (location != null) {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

                try {
                    obj.put("latitude", location.getLatitude());
                    obj.put("longitude", location.getLongitude());
                    obj.put("provider", location.getProvider());
                    return obj;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String getProvider() {
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
        criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
        criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
        criteria.setSpeedRequired(false);

        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        return provider;

    }
```

Thanks

**NOTE: it is not bad internet connection. Several users have started to complain of this issue. While othe apps which use geolocation work fine. It must be something in my code, but i cant figure out what. 
The weirdest thing is that it seems to work fine for a week or two, and then it starts happening in a lot of users at the same time**

Answer (score 4):

I would say that the problem is in the

```
criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
```

that maybe is just returning passive location provider. I would remove that, users now are aware that this kind of apps consume battery, so it wont be a forced criteria.

Anyways, I have a more complex class to retrieve location. Let me explain.

First, [from here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) i use this great function to determine  whether one Location reading is better than the current Location.

```
 /** 
 * @param location
 *            The new Location that you want to evaluate
 * @param currentBestLocation
 *            The current Location fix, to which you want to compare the new
 *            one
 */
protected boolean isBetterLocation(Location location,
        Location currentBestLocation) {
    if (currentBestLocation == null) {
        // A new location is always better than no location
        return true;
    }

    // Check whether the new location fix is newer or older
    long timeDelta = location.getTime() - currentBestLocation.getTime();
    boolean isSignificantlyNewer = timeDelta > TWO_MINUTES;
    boolean isSignificantlyOlder = timeDelta < -TWO_MINUTES;
    boolean isNewer = timeDelta > 0;

    // If it's been more than two minutes since the current location, use
    // the new location
    // because the user has likely moved
    if (isSignificantlyNewer) {
        return true;
        // If the new location is more than two minutes older, it must be
        // worse
    } else if (isSignificantlyOlder) {
        return false;
    }

    // Check whether the new location fix is more or less accurate
    int accuracyDelta = (int) (location.getAccuracy() - currentBestLocation
            .getAccuracy());
    boolean isLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 0;
    boolean isMoreAccurate = accuracyDelta < 0;
    boolean isSignificantlyLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 200;

    // Check if the old and new location are from the same provider
    boolean isFromSameProvider = isSameProvider(location.getProvider(),
            currentBestLocation.getProvider());

    // Determine location quality using a combination of timeliness and
    // accuracy
    if (isMoreAccurate) {
        return true;
    } else if (isNewer && !isLessAccurate) {
        return true;
    } else if (isNewer && !isSignificantlyLessAccurate
            && isFromSameProvider) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/** Checks whether two providers are the same */
private boolean isSameProvider(String provider1, String provider2) {
    if (provider1 == null) {
        return provider2 == null;
    }
    return provider1.equals(provider2);
}
```

Then, i create my own class that implements LocationListener (the activity, or a helper class, up to you). I just consider gps and network provider, but it is easily extensible

```
public class LocationObserver implements LocationListener {

    LocationManager lm;
    boolean gps_enabled = false;
    boolean network_enabled = false, network_connected = false;


    Context context;
    Long timeout; 
    int minTime;
    int minDistance;
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    private Location currentLocation = null;

    public LocationObserver(Context pContext, int minTime,
            int minDistance, long timeout) {

            this.context = pContext;
        this.timeout = timeout; 
        this.minDistance = minDistance;
        this.minTime = minTime;
    }
```

I create a method start where i consider which one is the best provider, or if i can listen to more than one

```
    public void start() {
        if (lm == null)
            lm = (LocationManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // exceptions will be thrown if provider is not permitted.
        try {
            gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
                //dont worry yet
        }
        try {
            network_enabled = lm
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            network_connected = activeNetwork != null
                    && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
              //dont wory yet
        }

            //now, lets see what happend,  

             //don't start listeners if no provider is enabled
        if (!gps_enabled && !network_enabled) {

            //nothing enabled, alert the user to enable any provide 
                   //Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS;



        }

        else { // one provider is enabled, and the other one is not


            if (gps_enabled) { // gps enabled, network disabled
                lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                        minTime, minDistance, this);

                //Consider asking the user to also enable network location ( Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS;=


            } else { // gps disabled, network enabled


                // check if actually there is a conection
                if (network_connected) {
                    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            minTime, minDistance, this);

                    //OK, Network is working, 
                    //consider asking the user to enable also gps (Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS;)

                } 

                //if network is not enabled, having the network location enabled is useles

                else  {

                     //ask the user to connect to any network ( Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS)
                }

            }
        }


            //retrieve the lastKnownLocation (we will see this function later) and call the callback to start using it
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Location l = getLastKnownLocation();
                onLocationChanged(l);

            }
        }, timeout);

    }
```

We made our own getLastKnownLocation(), that considers all the enabled providers, and returns the best location

```
    public Location getLastKnownLocation() {

        Location net_loc = null, gps_loc = null;
        if (gps_enabled)
            gps_loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (network_enabled)
            net_loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        // if there are both values use the best one
        if (gps_loc != null && net_loc != null) {
            if (isBetterLocation(gps_loc, net_loc))
                return gps_loc;
            else
                return net_loc;

        }

        else if (gps_loc != null) {
            return gps_loc;

        } else if (net_loc != null) {
            return net_loc;

        } else
            return null;
    }
```

And finally,  we write the     onLocationChanged callback, that the providers will call with any update. Since all the providers will call it, probably the upcoming location is worse than the one that we already have, so we also compare them

```
public synchronized void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        if (location == null || currentLocation == null
                || isBetterLocation(location, currentLocation)) {
            currentLocation = location;


            //do whatever you need with the new location

        }
    }

}
```

Also, what i use to do is to keep checking with a timer if a location come after the firstcall to getlastknowlocation. If an specific time passes, i check everything againg, to see what providers are enabled, or ask the user again to enable the disabled ones.

Also, some people like to rely directly in the Play Services Location Apis, where you dont have to worry about providers and without needing to focus on the details of the underlying location technology. https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html

Comment: Just a note to readers in 2018 going forwards - don't use `Location.getTime()` to compare location times. I followed the exact same example from Google Developers (`isBetterLocation()`) and had a weird problem with some location updates seemingly being 24 hours ahead of others. Using `getRealTimeNanos()` is the way to go on API 17>, Google even discourage use of `getTime()` themselves but apparently haven't updated that sample in 4 years...

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using `getLastKnownLocation()` when you don't expect to.  Your implementation of `getLastKnownLocation()` uses the last result from the location manager if available, or the the last known location if nothing is available.  So, if your users turn off location services, your app will continually use the last location it saw, from  `makeUseOfNewLocation()`, or the last location that the phone saw, from `locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider)`.  This would explain the behavior you are seeing, that the code returns the same old location continuously.

To solve this issue, you can use the callbacks onProviderEnabled/onProviderDisabled to notify your app that it shouldn't keep using lastKnownLocation.  You can also check to see if your location services are connected before you use a location, using locationManager.isProviderEnabled() or locationClient.isConnected(), and prompt the user to reenable them.

Answer (score 1):

```
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

is causing the issue. `getLastKnownLocation(provider)` provides the last location which is gathered or used by any location based application in user`s smartphone.

You can use **Sharedpreferences** to save location data in your application, so that you can use it as lastknownlocation when required.

Answer (score 0):

Try in this manner:

and use bestProvider

```
// Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

            // Getting the name of the best provider
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

            // Getting Current Location From GPS
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            if(location!=null)
            {                                       
                onLocationChanged(location);
            }

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);
```

Comment: So, it's due to bad internet connection. I think not in your code problem

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK location is derived from the "best" source available to the Android device. That means GPS capability or location as reported by the browser (via Google location services). Since each device differs you will get differing results. Do you have a dedicated GPS capable device, preferrably using 3G (or better comms) - you will get the best location results that way. I think this that this is a bug as such, just the reality of trying to location your device across whatever network it is currently connected to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{
protected LocationManager locationManager;
protected LocationListener locationListener;
protected Context context;
TextView txtLat;
String lat;
String provider;
protected String latitude,longitude; 
protected boolean gps_enabled,network_enabled;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);

locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
txtLat.setText("Latitude:" + location.getLatitude() + ", Longitude:" + location.getLongitude());
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
Log.d("Latitude","disable");
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
Log.d("Latitude","enable");
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
Log.d("Latitude","status");
}
}
```

Also make sure you have specified the following permissions in your manifest file:-

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need an accurate position fix, explicitly set the location provider to read GPS (yes it uses more battery).

`criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);`

This will use passive location using wifi signals & mobile phone signal towers in the area where you are and I think this is where it goes wrong!!

POWER_LOW uses the IP geo-location of whatever wifi/mobile phone signal is near you.

According to http://www.ipligence.com/geolocation the location of my static IP address is 170km north of my actual location. So, if you use my wifi signal to get a position fix, it will be off by 170km.

even mobile phone signals will only locate your place on triangulation of signal towers in the area and is not the most accurate as they overlap each other a good bit to keep signal strength up.

Having played with this on an android app I made I say the idea of a passive location provider is good in theory, not workable in reality for positioning.

and there is a conflict in your criteria:

```
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
```

ACCURACY_FINE means use the GPS as a locationprovider (use heavy battery).
POWER_LOW means use low powerusage locationprovider (therefore DON'T use GPS)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you implement the [Location's API](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html) new `LocationClient`. All the algorithms regarding which provider to choose are done for you; it always uses the best provider available thanks to the fused provider. It also uses other sensors to get the most accurate location possible.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have the very same problem. I can see it not only in code but also in behavior with other devices.

Google maps on my HTC Sensation shows me locations from last week witch is happened to be the last time I run the app and its the only app that use locations on my phone.

So I came to conclusion that this cash is some how managed on the driver it self.

I solved this problem by **ignoring** those results. I always remember the last **new** location data I received and know to ignore it when it's not relevant.